# rails csrf validation in firefox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, csrf

I have a site created with Rails using Devise for authentication. It works perfectly fine in Chrome, but in Firefox I cannot log in. All I can see is a message in log:
`WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity`
And the login screen comes back without any error messages.

Can someone give me a hint where to look after what is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem. Login was working in Chrome and not in FF.
The problem was not related to CSRF since I commented out `protect_from_forgery` and tried to signin but I wasn't allowed to. The only difference was that the warning message disappeared.

After some debugging I found out that the problem is related to session and :domain => :all setting for the session store.

```
MyApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_myapp_session', :domain => :all
```

After I removed `:domain => all`, I was able to login using Firefox. Hope that this will help someone even though the answer arrives two months late.