# Getting CSRF Error with Firefox and Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, firefox, devise, csrf

For some reason my application won't login on firefox. It throws a CSRF error, although all tags are present and submitting successfully. Login also works on any other browser.

I found an answer that referenced changing:

`Learn::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_learn_session', domain: :all`

to

`Learn::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_learn_session'`

in `config/initializers/session_store.rb`

I've tried with both (and initially had it without `domain: :all`) but neither seem to work.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132050/rails-csrf-validation-in-firefox?rq=1) references my issue, but the answer is was not helpful in my situation.

To further complicate the situation, I've tested without CSRF enabled, and the app simply prevents a login without a failure notification.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you add the relevant pieces of your HTML (meta tags and/or form definition) and the `params` hash as show on your console for a login-request before it is denied? Maybe your `before` filter from the controller is relevant as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you ever checked your cookie?

I encountered the same problem earlier today and it turned out to be a problem with my cookie configuration. As your application still won't work without CSRF enabled, I think either your login_controller or session_store has bugs. Read `session_store.rb` and `your_environment.rb` carefully and maybe you can find what's wrong.

Comment: WOW! I actually had cookies turned off in firefox and spent 4 hours trying to track down issues in the app. This was enough to remind me that I should probably check on that. Thanks!.

Comment: I did exactly the same thing, had somehow blocked cookies from localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Wow. I managed to do this again (see comment on Tim's answer), so I'm really writing this answer to my future self. Specifically, Firefox had blocked cookies from localhost.

If I unblocked the cookies, after a while Firefox automatically blocks them again, requiring them to be unblocked. I'm not yet clear on why this happens, but at least the work around is obvious (Chrome).